# Are arguments of after plugin mandatory?

Tags: magento2, plugin

I am writing tiny plugin on `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Edit:execute()`. It's `after` one. I have just noticed that I am not using any arguments inside my method.

```
/**
 * Method modify redirection when changing password.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Edit $subject.
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $results
 * 
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
 */
public function afterExecute(MagentoEdit $subject, $results)
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    /** @var $resultRedirect \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect */
    return $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
}
```

I have tested method with no arguments inserted and it has worked. Is it any mistake or I don't really need arguments in `after` plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically you should still return `$result` but the reason this works for you is because controller actions are not checked for return values . Plus, you redirect before return value could be reached.

It doesn't seem as though there is anything wrong with the way you wrote the plugin. I would just get rid of the type hint and do it more like this sample below.

```
/**
 * Method modify redirection when changing password.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Edit $subject.
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $results
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
 */
public function afterExecute($subject, $result)
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    /** @var $resultRedirect \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect */
    $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: So what I should do in order to make it correct? I should change `$results` by assigning to it `$resultRedirect->setUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());`?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Why do you think is good or useful to get rid of type hint?

Comment: Because its unnecessary and if you look at the way other plugings are being written, they don't use them in this scenario. There's nothing wrong with it if it works, its just a suggestion though.

Comment: ok - I will test your anserw soon.

Comment: actually if return `$result` after setting redirection to referer, I am changing page - I have to return `return $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());` to change controller behavior.

Comment: That makes perfect sense actually, I did not have occasion to test my answer.

Comment: Ok then, point of my question was to consider if params of `after` method are unused inside function, they still should be included or ommited.

Comment: Usually the result is needed to be returned in the before, around, and after plugins and they do indeed get used. However, yours is a different situation bc you are implementing a redirect. I use after plugins all the time, not for redirects but for other functions and the return value does get used.

Comment: I use them for other purposes too, but here was the first time I didn't used any of arguments provided. Majority of cases - a change the `$results` and return changed output. Thanks.